# Why changes are not being updated on the website posts?

Tags: r, hugo, blogdown

When I change/update contents of the already published post, updates show in the local machine with serve_site, however changes won't update in the website.
Changes for other sections such as resume are updated on the website. Here is link to blog - https://knitdata.org/ and repo at https://github.com/knitdata/minrblog. The site is built with blogdown, hugo(academic theme) and deployed through netlify. No issues with production deploys.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Could you mention which sections aren't updated on the live site? Had a look over the sources and I couldn't figure it out. I see you are using Netlify - did you have a look over there, did it pick up the latest changes, did it show any errors? Are the changes you mention on the remote repository (on GitHub)? Maybe you didn't push the latest changes from your local repo.

Comment: @AMoustache posts sections aren't updated. I had no issues on Netlify, each change is deployed properly. I assume issue is not with netlify. Changes are on Github and changes are pushed after each update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's some temporary cache on your side. I have read few of your last commits than modify existing posts and I can see changes on your web. E.g. the last commit shows properly, this sentence is new:

[image: screenshot]

Deploing changes through git, GitHub and Netlify can take some time and can be cached somewhere. So when visiting your web after some change, try to force refresh (e.g. by `Ctrl+Shift+R`, if you use Chrome-based browser).

Comment: right, sometimes change do appear after a while. I  removed comments you posted on my posts and pushed to Github, almost 10 hours now , changes haven't updated yet on web. Unless changes take more than that to appear which I assume shouldn't be the case. Changes are immediate with other sections. Not aware of temporary cache, I will need to dig deeper.

Comment: @MinR Ah, I see your file structure: your posts contain not only .Rmd files, but also generated HTML files. For the "Topic modeling" post you have updated your Rmd file on GitHub, but the folder contains also older HTML file with the old content, see [here](https://github.com/knitdata/minrblog/blob/master/content/post/topic-modeling/index.html). That's why you don't see your updates - it takes that HTML file! You'll need to push only source files to git and let Netlify fully generate your site.

Comment: Thank you @Petr Kajzar. It works now. Apparently I pushed commit too soon and netlify was picking initial HTML file.

Comment: @MinR, How was the issue resolved. I am also facing similar issue. I am using chrome browser. My changes are visible locally, and code generated in public folder is successfully checkin in github. Its been a while and I cannot see the changes reflected in github static website: https://naresh-chaurasia.github.io/talk2naresh/. The code is available here: https://github.com/Naresh-Chaurasia/talk2naresh

Comment: @NareshChaurasia sorry for the late reply.  Hope your issue was solved. I followed the steps mentioned above. When you save, wait a while  before push commit so that change is reflected on HTML file otherwise it will kick initial file.